# Extract model saved in S3 bucket as tar.gz format to sagemaker notebook instance

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I have a tar.gz file inside a S3 bucket, this is a file containing 6 different 'pickled' model zipped together. This was created after training a model with SageMaker docker container in single run.

In order to make an inference, I would like untar these models into separate models to run model.predict() on the test data.

My S3 bucket structure: 's3:///output/train_best_params/model.tar.gz'

How can I download these into SageMaker notebook instance and extract the 6 different models from it: as model1, model2, ....

If I simply use sagemaker.model.Model() method, I couldn't make any inference, because this model object will have multiple models inside it.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to host these as real time endpoints, or simply run `model.predict()` from the notebook? If it is the latter, you can copy the tarfile to your notebook like `aws s3 cp s3:///output/train_best_params/model.tar.gz .` and then untar using `tar -xvf model.tar.gz`. If you're hosting, take a look at multi-model endpoints [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/multi-model-endpoints.html)

Comment: I plan to use batch transform to make inferences. It will be hosted but run once a week, so probably not real-time endpoints.

Comment: Yup, this is it! I just needed to see what was inside the tar.gz.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would have to write some script to download the tar.gz file from the training job output and individually seperate the models into different tar.gz files ( you will have 6 in this case) along with corresponding inference.py files. Then you can deploy them separately using batch transform -
https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker_batch_transform/pytorch_mnist_batch_transform/pytorch-mnist-batch-transform.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

1. If your model is predicting the same thing you might want to recheck the training script whether it is saving multiple times or it is just a checkpoints. I suggest you pick the best one from validation or remove duplications.
2. If your 6 models are predicting different features, and you want to run it all at the same time, I suggest you download the file, extract it, compress it separately and upload it back separately.

If creating the models is more like a one-time thing, you don't need to create a script and proceed with creating the model in sagemaker. Here's an example of how I did it.

```
import boto3
sm_client = boto3.client(service_name='sagemaker')
container = {
    'Image': 'my_account_id.dkr.ecr.my_region.amazonaws.com/my_model_repo_name:latest',
    'ModelDataUrl': 'path/to/your/model.tar,gz',
    'Mode': 'SingleModel'
}
create_model_response = sm_client.create_model(
    ModelName ='my_model',
    ExecutionRoleArn = 'my_role',
    Containers = [container],
    Tags=[{'my_tag':'somethingcool'}])

print("Model Arn: " + create_model_response['ModelArn'])
```

Comment: the 6 models are predicting different features. And I want to update the model once a week automatically when the input data is changed. So, trying to avoid manual download/upload of the model from/to S3 bucket.